# DLL interop / interesting error

Tags: c++, c, pointers, interop

```
char ARRAY[1024]; // <-- global
```

---

### Code below works

```
myFunctionInDll("some string"); // everything ok
```

---

### Code below doesn't work

```
myFunctionInDll(ARRAY); // after compilation the entry point of DLL cannot be found
```

So, to sum up, if I pass a "static string" to my function inside my dll the dll compiles and loads perfectly.  However, if I populate the global array (chars) and then try and pass that to my function, again it compiles but when I try and call the function from my C# app I get 'entry point cannot be found.'  This is really strange and I can find no reason why...

Thanks RU.

Anyone know why?

Comment: What is the function prototype for myFunctionInDll?

Answer (score 1):

Did you write the interop or are you just using the .NET generated interop class?  If the later try

```
string myStr = "some string";
myFunctionInDll(myStr);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks joe.  This sounds counter intuitive but I later realised that I was actually doing things correctly which is why it wasn't working...  It was part of a rootkit test for a uni project and I realised that the module was being hidden, which is why the string function couldn't be passed to the dll, because it couldn't see it!  Pretty funny actually :)